# Get min value based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, min

I have the following list

```
L= [383, 590, 912, 618, 203, 982, 364, 131, 343, 202]
```

If I use the function `min(L)` I get `131`

Is it possible to know the min value in the list of numbers that exceed 200?
I guess something like `min(L, Key>200)`

The desired result would be 202

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `min()` function in combination with a list traversal using a `for` loop as follows to introduce conditions when finding minimums:

```
L= [383, 590, 912, 618, 203, 982, 364, 131, 343, 202]
m = min(i for i in L if i > 200)
print(m)
```

**Output:**

```
202
```

Comment: Upvote for using a generator rather than (the common mistake of) creating another list inside `min()`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no limitation on using any other libraries, it can be easily achieved by indexing in NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

s = np.array(L)
s[s > 200].min()
# 202
```

Using NumPy on large arrays are much recommended, which can easily handle such problems in more efficient way in terms of performance and memory usage (on large arrays).

Answer (score 0):

this solution isn't as fast as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72775178/18344512), just an alternative:

```
min(L, key=lambda x: x>200 and x or float('inf'))
```